# Library like Universal Image Loader to load files (audio, video, text, etc) in background

Tags: android, multithreading, audio, video, download

I know that i can use Universal Image Loader Library to load Images in background, but i wander if I can find library to do the same behavior for other file formats like (audio, video).

Pleas help

Comment: You can use OkHttp or Ion to download this kind of files on your phone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OkHttp or Ion to download this kind of files on your phone!

https://github.com/koush/ion

http://square.github.io/okhttp/